# Did anyone ever figure out how to correctly encode plain text/RTF/HTML to the PR_RTF_COMPRESSED format?

Tags: outlook

I'm referring to streams of the type _substg1.0_10090102 in an Outlook message file, which I believe are in the PR_RTF_COMPRESSED format.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you curious about the compression details? Or the actual data inside that property and how to RTF encode plain text and HTML? Take a look at PR_RTF_COMPRESSED property in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button).

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry!  I'm interested in how to actually transform plain text into the encoded format.  I'll take a look at the property you mentioned.